# How to derive SwiftUI state from an ObserverableObject property of an ObserverableObject?

Tags: swiftui

Here is my example [SwiftUI](https://github.com/saltzmanjoelh/CombineObservableObject) project. I have an ObservableObject class (Resource) that fetches data and uses @Published to publish the value it fetches.

```
class Resource: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value: User?

    func saveToDb(email: String) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            //save to remote db
            let user = User.init(email: email)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.value = user
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a second ObservableObject class (Authenticator) that represents an authentication state that also uses @Published to publish it's state. The Authenticator's state is derived from it's Resource having a value or not.

```
class Authenticator: ObservableObject {

    @Published var needsAuthentication = true
    //Can this be derived from resource.value != nil instead of subscribing to it
    //UI doesn't appear to update when this is changed unless I use the subscription
    @Published var resource = Resource()

    var subscription: AnyCancellable?

    public init() {
        subscription = resource.$value.map({ (user: User?) -> Bool in
            user == nil
        })
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .assign(to: \Authenticator.needsAuthentication, on: self)
    }
    deinit {
        subscription?.cancel()
    }

    func doSignInWithAppleStuff() {
        let email = "fromSignInWithAppleResult@email.com"
        resource.saveToDb(email: email)
    }
}
```

I'm currently using the steps described in the [Combine docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/receiving-and-handling-events-with-combine) to subscribe to the Resource's value and update the Authenticator and subsequently the UI.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var authenticator = Authenticator()
    var body: some View {
        //How do I skip using the authenticators state and use the resource directly?
        if authenticator.needsAuthentication {
            Button("Sign In") {
                authenticator.doSignInWithAppleStuff()
            }
        } else {
            Text("Success")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
struct User {
    let email: String
}
```

Is there an alternative SwiftUI/Combine tool that can help the Autenticator.needsAuthentication property to represent that the resource has a value without manually creating the subscription?

I have tried disabling the subscription and using `$authenticator.resource.value.wrappedValue == nil` but the UI doesn't update. I'm guessing because the authenticator is not publishing the change of it's resource property.